# Is a DOM HTMLCollection - array-like-Element a constant using ES6?

Tags: javascript

I would like to understand if I can treat a HTMLCollection as an constand using const keyword (ES6) or better treat as a variable using the var keyword.

What´s making me getting confudes is the fact, that const buttons is changing in the for-loop, but beeing accessed over the array-like object.

```js
(function IIFE() {
    'use strict';
    
    
    
    const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    
    for (let i = 0, l = buttons.length; i < l; i += 1) {
        buttons[i].onclick = function () {
            
            for (let i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
                
                buttons[i].className = '';
                
                this.className = 'active';
            }
            
        };
    }
    
    
    
    console.log(typeof(buttons)); // object
    console.log(buttons);         // HTMLCollection
    
    
}());
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 196px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

button {
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: , "andale mono";
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}



.active {
    background: rgba(51, 181, 229, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test UI</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <ul>
        <li><button class="active">A</button></li>
        <li><button>B</button></li>
        <li><button>C</button></li>
    </ul>
                                 
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `buttons` itself is not changed, only the elements which the live collection referes to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What´s making me getting confudes is the fact, that const buttons is
>   changing in the for-loop, but beeing accessed over the array-like
>   object.

`const` keyword only *prevents you from changing the value* (primitive or reference) of the variable. **You can still modify the properties of the variable**.

So you **can't** do the following

```
const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');//this line will throw an error with or without const again
```

But you **can** do the following

```
const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
buttons[0].className = ''; //only property is being modified not the object reference value itself
```